# Google Drive API v3 doesn't list specified metadata of file/folder

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, metadata, google-api-js-client

Hello I'am in trouble trying to retrieve specified metadata fields with the Google Drive API v3 and javascript.

I use generic API request for that:

```
gapi.client.request({
          'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId,
          'fields': "files(id, name, size, parents)",
          'method': 'GET'
        })
```

but the response lists just

```
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "id": "0B99ZF.........Z",
    "name": "...",
    "mimeType": "..."
```

How can list the metadata specified in the request:

```
'fields': 'files(id, name, size, parents)'
```

Thank you for the reply.

Comment: does the file have any parents? Is it a binary file or a Google doc? what does fields:* return? What do you get if you try it with the online tool https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get ?

Comment: The file is a .txt file in the root location. fields:* return just the same metadata

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have constructed the parameter object to `gapi.client.request` incorrectly. Try...

```
gapi.client.request({
          'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/'+fileId,
          'params' : {'fields': "*"},
          'method': 'GET' 
        })
```

or simply add `&fields=*` to your URL. See https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/reference/referencedocs#gapiclientrequest

Comment: Yeah, It works now! It wasn't quite obvious in the Google documentation, so thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [`Files#list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) endpoint, then the proper `"fields"` specification to retrieve the fileId, name, size, and parent ids would indeed be `"fields": "files(id,name,size,parents)"`, because the response to `Files#list` is:

> {
>  
>     "kind": "drive#fileList",
>  
>     "nextPageToken": string,
>  
>     "incompleteSearch": boolean,
>  
>     "files": [
>   
>       [`files Resource`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource)
>  
>     ]
>   }

e.g. there is a path that goes `response -> files -> your-metadata-fields`

However, for [`Files#get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get#response), the response is the metadata directly - not wrapped in any pagination markers:

> {
>  
>     "kind": "drive#file",
>  
>     "id": string,
>  
>     "name": string,
>  
>     "mimeType": string,
>  
>     "description": string,
>  
>     "starred": boolean,
>  
>     "trashed": boolean,
>  
>     ...
>   }

Thus, the fields path prefix `files` results in an invalid field specification, because the path is `response -> your-metadata-fields`

Without this "files" prefix, and with your [corrected request construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51425934/9337071) your generic request looks like:

```
...
gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId,
      'params': { 'fields': "id,name,size,parents" },
      'method': 'GET'
    });
...
```

Edit: as indicated by @pinoyyid, the request was not properly setting the "fields" query parameter.

Comment: Thank you @tehhowch for the reply but It doesn't work. I guess now if the DISCOVERY_DOCS and SCOPES are wrong. `DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/drive/v3/rest"]` and `SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata'`

Comment: @PierpaoloFernandez see the correction I've included from the other answer. Without "fields" being properly set as a query parameter, you get only the generic metadata (as your tests have revealed).